# Gaussian fit for python with confidence interval

Tags: python, gaussian

I'd like to make a Gaussian Fit for some data that has a rough gaussian fit. I'd like the information of data peak (A), center position (mu), and standard deviation (sigma), along with 95% confidence intervals for these values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import norm

# gaussian function
def gaussian_func(x, A, mu, sigma):
    return A * np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

# generate toy data
x = np.arange(50)
y = [ 97.04421053,  96.53052632,  96.85684211,  96.33894737,  96.85052632,
  96.30526316,  96.87789474,  96.75157895,  97.05052632,  96.73473684,
  96.46736842,  96.23368421,  96.22526316,  96.11789474,  96.41263158,
  96.32631579,  96.33684211,  96.44421053,  96.48421053,  96.49894737,
  97.30105263,  98.58315789, 100.07368421, 101.43578947, 101.92210526,
 102.26736842, 101.80421053, 101.91157895, 102.07368421, 102.02105263,
 101.35578947,  99.83578947,  98.28,        96.98315789,  96.61473684,
  96.82947368,  97.09263158,  96.82105263,  96.24210526,  95.95578947,
  95.84210526,  95.67157895,  95.83157895,  95.37894737,  95.25473684,
  95.32842105,  95.45684211,  95.31578947,  95.42526316,  95.30526316]
plt.scatter(x,y)

# initial_guess_of_parameters
# この値はソルバーとかで求めましょう．
parameter_initial = np.array([652, 2.9, 1.3])

# estimate optimal parameter & parameter covariance
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian_func, x, y, p0=parameter_initial)

# plot result
xd = np.arange(x.min(), x.max(), 0.01)
estimated_curve = gaussian_func(xd, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
plt.plot(xd, estimated_curve, label="Estimated curve", color="r")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("gaussian_fitting.png")
plt.show()

# estimate standard Error
StdE = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))

# estimate 95% confidence interval
alpha=0.025
lwCI = popt + norm.ppf(q=alpha)*StdE
upCI = popt + norm.ppf(q=1-alpha)*StdE

# print result
mat = np.vstack((popt,StdE, lwCI, upCI)).T
df=pd.DataFrame(mat,index=("A", "mu", "sigma"),
columns=("Estimate", "Std. Error", "lwCI", "upCI"))
print(df)
```

[Data Plot with Fitted Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byRIb.png)

The data peak and center position seems correct, but the standard deviation is off. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your scatter indeed looks similar to a gaussian distribution, but it is not centered around zero. Given the specifics of the Gaussian function it will therefor be hard to nicely fit a Gaussian distribution to the data the way you gave us. I would therefor propose by starting with demeaning the x series:

`x = np.arange(0, 50) - 24.5`

Next I would add one additional parameter to your gaussian function, the offset. Since the regular Gaussian function will always have its tails close to zero it is impossible to otherwise nicely fit your scatterplot:

```
def gaussian_function(x, A, mu, sigma, offset):
    return A * np.exp(-np.power((x - mu)/sigma, 2.)/2.) + offset
```

Next you should define an error_loss_function to minimise:

```
def error_loss_function(params):
    gaussian = gaussian_function(x, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3])
    errors = gaussian - y
    return sum(np.power(errors, 2))  # You can also pick a different error loss function!
```

All that remains is fitting our curve now:

```
fit = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=error_loss_function, x0=[2, 0, 0.2, 97])
params = fit.x  # A: 6.57592661,  mu: 1.95248855,  sigma: 3.93230503, offset: 96.12570778

xd = np.arange(x.min(), x.max(), 0.01)
estimated_curve = gaussian_function(xd, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3])
plt.plot(xd, estimated_curve, label="Estimated curve", color="b")
plt.legend()
plt.show(block=False)
```

[image]

Hopefully this helps. Looks like a fun project, let me know if my answer is not clear.